# Find the best least squares approximation of $\sqrt x$ by a function from the subspace $S$.

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

> Consider the inner product space $C[0,1]$ with inner product $$\langle
> f,g\rangle =\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\,dx$$ Let $S$ be the subspace spanned by
>   $1$ and $2x-1$
>
> Find the best least squares approximation of $\sqrt x$ by a function
>   from the subspace $S$.

---

What exactly is the relationship between least squares approximation and orthonormal vectors? In other words, I would appreciate if this question were explained to me in the most basic way.

I know that we use $$p=\sum_ic_iu_i \quad c_i=\langle x,u_i\rangle$$
where $u_i$ are the vectors in the orthonormal basis.

But $p = A\hat{x} $ and I thought we were supposed to be looking for $\hat{x} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least square approximation of a function $f$ by a function from a subspace $S$ is the projection $f$ of onto $S$. You have denoted it by it $p$ in the question.

An orthonormal basis just simplifies our working using the formula that you have pointed out.

$$p=\sum_ic_iu_i \quad c_i=\langle f,u_i\rangle \tag{1}$$

where $u_i$ forms an orthornomal basis.

Guide:

We should first check if $\{ 1, 2x-1\}$ is an orthonormal basis and if it is not, we can construct an orthonomal basis. Verify that

$$\int_0^1 1^2 \, dx = 1$$

$$\int_0^1 1 \cdot (2x-1) \, dx = 0$$
$$\int_0^1 (2x-1)^2 \, dx= \frac13$$

Hence it is not orthonormal. It is just orthogonal.

Note that we have $$\int_0^1 ((\sqrt3)\cdot (2x-1) )^2 \, dx= 1$$

Try to construct an orthornormal basis and then use formula $(1)$ to compute its projection.